# Day trip to Zugspitze, from Munich

Tags: public-transport, germany, day-trips, alps, munich

I am planning to visit Munich at the beginning of the next month. I will be staying there three to four days. One of my main attraction is to have a one day trip to Zugspitze. I am interested to know the possible ways to visit there from Munich and the approximate cost.

It will be really great if someone suggests the route to the top of the mountain from Munich HBF (including train, cable train). It will also be great if you please tell the accommodation facility (youth hostel) nearby if I need to stay a night.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to take a train from Munich to Garmisch-Partenkirchen, and from there the rack railway to the Zugspitze. The journey takes almost three hours and the trains from Munich to Garmisch run hourly. Thus it is possible to do a round trip from Munich in one day.

Here are some recommended schedules:

[image]

The round trip from Munich to the Zugspitze costs 59 EUR with a so-called "[Garmischer Sommer-Ticket](http://zugspitze.de/de/sommer/berge/garmisch-classic/garmischer-sommer-ticket)".

For more information on schedules you can have a look at the [website of the German Railways](http://bahn.de). Informations about cable cars and alike can be found on the official website of the [Bavarian Zugspitz Mountain Railways](http://zugspitze.de/).

Comment: Is Bayern ticket included with this price?

Comment: No. The price includes a train ticket valid for that day between Munich and Garmisch, as well as a day ticket for the mountain railroads.